Replace Firefox with chrome
Please I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my dell altitude pc. The first action I took was to replace firefox with chrome. So I downloaded google chrome. Then I installed it using sudo dpkg -i path-to-google-chrome.
This worked successfully and I set chrome as my favorite browser.
Except that after that, I saw a red circle with a white line indicating the following error:
"an error occurred please run package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in terminal to see what is wrong . E : unknown error: '<class 'keyError'>' ("the cache has no package named 'firefox:amd64'"). this usually means that your installed package have unmet dependencies"
I'm native on Ubuntu I don't know how to fix this.
Can someone please help me?

Try running: sudo apt -f install

Ubuntu 20.04 is four years old. Community support for it ends in one year.

What do you mean by replace Firefox with chrome? More details are needed I think you may have done more then what you have written here.
